# protoc compiler error out of range for enum value 0x88000000

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-c

In proto file I have one enum like I am converting it c++ code 
It throws error Integer out of range for field(_G,_P,_L) . In https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#enum  says "Enumerator constants must be in the range of a 32-bit integer" . Please help me fix this issue

enum  field are

```
 pb_EnumTargetType_A = 0x40000000;
 tpb_EnumTargetType_G = 0x88000000;
 tpb_EnumTargetType_P = 0x8C000000;
  tpb_EnumTargetType_L = 0x8A000000;
```

Comment: Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Use `code blocking` for code and log and error texts and **bold** and *italics* to highlight things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it is interpreting this as a *positive* number, which would therefore require more than 32-bits to encode as a signed integer. Writing it as a signed integer seems to work:

```
pb_EnumTargetType_A = 0x40000000;
tpb_EnumTargetType_G = -2013265920; // 0x88000000
tpb_EnumTargetType_P = -1946157056; // 0x8C000000
tpb_EnumTargetType_L = -1979711488; // 0x8A000000
```